# Compositor not working inside adaptive smoke domain

Tags: compositing-nodes, smoke-simulation

I have created a circle mesh and set it up as an emission.  I also added a compositor for it to add blur and glare effects.  I have set up a smoke domain and two flow objects.  The smoke domain also has adaptive domain turned on.

If I place the circle outside the main smoke domain it renders and composites just fine.  If I place it inside the main domain, but outside the adaptive domain it again renders and composites fine.  However, if I place it inside the adaptive domain it does not composite.

Why? and/or what am doing wrong?

BTW, I'm new here...I have a small test .blend file for this issue, but I can't figure out how to attach it to this question so I'm hoping my description above makes sense.

Comment: Is this the same question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/93058/1853 ?

Comment: Yes.  I posted that one first as a guest but didn't see any feedback that made me believe it went through so I opened an account and posted again.  Sorry for the duplication...newbie...